# Java Swing - Finder Text Box

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I current have a JFrame application that uses JTextField's for input of file location as per the code below.

```
    txtSource = new JTextField();
    txtSource.setToolTipText("/location/of/file/test.txt");
    txtSource.setText("/location/of/file/test.txt");
    txtSource.setBounds(16, 122, 412, 29);
    contentPane.add(txtSource);
    txtSource.setColumns(10);
```

What I would like to do is allow a directory search for the user to select the location of the file on the local computer and that location would populate into the Textbox.

I found the below information on JCHooser, but I'm not sure if this is way to go and would like assistance on how to implement.

```
String filename = File.separator+"tmp";
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File(filename));

// Show open dialog; this method does not return until the dialog is closed
fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
File selFile = fc.getSelectedFile();

// Show save dialog; this method does not return until the dialog is closed
fc.showSaveDialog(frame);
selFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k24471o6/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
    int option = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            txtSource.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath())
    }
```

populates the text field with the selected file absolute file location

Comment: If you only want the user to be able to select directories, you should supply `JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY` to the `JFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode`.  This will cause the chooser to only show directories - if that's what you're trying to do ;)

Comment: Worked great. Cheers for that.